# Can breadth first search traverse a disconnected graph?

Tags: graph

I have an exam question:

Consider the undirected graph with vertices the numbers 3..16, and edges given by the following rule: two vertices a and b are linked by an edge whenever a is a factor of b, or b is a factor of a. List the vertices in BFS order starting from 14. (Many different orders are possible with a BFS, you may list any one of these).

I'm considering two answers:

1. Because the graph is not connected, from 14 BFS can only traverse to 7, so the result is 14, 7.
2. List out all the first level disconnected vertices, then traverse to their child nodes.
   so, 14, 16, 15, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9,   7, 8, 6, 5, 4, 3

Which one is correct? 
Can BFS traverse to disconnected vertices?

Comment: BSF can't traverse different components of the graph. In fact, one of the applications of the BFS algorithm is to find all the nodes within a connected component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer 2 doesn't make sense in my opinion, because this requires knowledge about which nodes are disconnected. Which you need the algorithm to find out. So I'd say answer 1 is correct.